# how address path works in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I want to load html5 page, in my UIWebView in xcode, when I added files in my project for example: "for my html5:

I have css folder I have javascript file I have images, and my folder structure is like:

css/
javascript/
images/

when I adde these folders in xcode and I run the program, xcode can n't get the address, it can load the html page but with out any  picture, javascript and css since they are in the other folders, I know, when I put all file together not in separate folder everything works but I want to have real folder structure in my xcode (I don't want to use group) would you please help me

for example

here it's works

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"about.html" ofType:nil]];
```

but when I add about in one folder like

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test/about.html" ofType:nil]];
```

the link it dosent work, How can I fixed this path problem in xcode

when I run about.html if all css,javascript and images are located in about folder everything works in xcode

but when I have them in separate folder about can not load the css / javascript and images

would you please give me some hints

Thanks in advance!

Edit ::

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"page1.html" ofType:nil]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

I want to use something like this folder : test/

```
[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test/page1.html" ofType:nil]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the baseURL of your `UIWebView` instance to be the URL of the directory in your main bundle with the content in it, and your links from your html need to be relative.

The code below is a basic way, given my content is in the root of the main bundle.

```
//find my html file
NSString *htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"htmlfile-to-load" ofType:@"html"];
//load it into an NSData
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath];
//get the URL of the bundles resource directory
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] isDirectory:YES];
//load tableView
[self.webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```

You may need to get your baseURL differently, but that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you for you reply would you please give me one example

Comment: sorry for lots of question , but I can not run your code, but when I use this code in EDIT part I can just one page with out new path